# jump to the first nonblank character in vim inside tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I have this function in my vimrc to jump to the first nonblank character on the line:

```
function! SmartHome()
  let s:col = col(".")
  normal! ^
  if s:col == col(".")
    normal! 0
  endif
endfunction
```

This works well outside of a tmux session.
But inside of a tmux session it will just jump to the first character on the line - which is wrong!

I have mapped this function this way:

```
" smart home function
nnoremap <silent> <Home> :call SmartHome()<CR>
inoremap <silent> <Home> <C-O>:call SmartHome()<CR>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the point of that function? Can't you just use `^`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by removing the following line from my .bashrc file

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

This works since xterm and the screen "like" protocol from tmux does not send/expect the same values for the HOME key:

```
$ tput -T screen khome | xxd
0000000: 1b5b 317e                                .[1~
$ tput -T xterm khome | xxd
0000000: 1b4f 48                                  .OH
```

Comment: The recommended `TERM` for tmux is `sceen-256color`.

Comment: Yes, I have this in my tmux configuration